# Biztalk File Adapter Duplication

Tags: biztalk

biztalk 2010 cu4, win2k8 server, no anti virus

I'm having an issue where the biztalk file adapter is picking up the exact same file twice intermittently. This happens to both receive locations that are either unc remote or local across 2 different receive locations in 2 different applications.

The receive location has all default settings. I've tried setting rename files ticked and unticked with no resolution to the issue. The file masks are of \H3OR*.txt.

The time of pickup being the 'unparsed interchanges' between the duplicates is never greater than 1 second. 2 ms is common. Looking at the unparsed interchanges of the duplicates, the context properties 'receivedfilename' is exactly the same. The occurrence of the duplication is roughly 1 in 8 files being received.

The receive location does have credentials to the unc path and it does delete files after it's done with them.

Restarting both the receive location and the biztalk host has no effect.

Let me know if you need any more info.

thanks.

Comment: Can you check in the event log for an error like `The FILE receive adapter cannot delete file XXX
This file processed successfully.
Please delete this file from the disk` ? However, this will typically only duplicate the batch after the specified retry interval. Edit: Are you saying that you have the same receive location specified twice in different applications?

Comment: Nothing in the event log. No, they are totally different applications and locations. But both exhibit same duplication problem.

Comment: The underlying storage could also be the issue. Do you have any other BizTalk receive locations pointed towards the same file server? Do you have the same issue for these flows? If yes -> your file server/share might be the issue here. If no -> this has something to do with the source of the files.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the problem lies elsewhere. Are you sure the upstream process, which creates these files, in the first place, isn't duplicating them i.e. sending the same file in quick succession? 
You might test this by creating another send port, which subscribes to these files but writes them out to a folder but appends the %MessageID% to the %SourceFileName%.
If you have 2 files with the same %SourceFileName% but different %MessageID% with 1 or more  seconds apart, it proves the problem is upstream.

Comment: I don't think so. The process which drops the files off has been running for years including before biztalk was implemented. This problem only started occurring when biztalk was turned on. I've checked a recent sample of the problem and the message id is different. Still with a few milliseconds difference between creation time. Unfortunately I've given up on this problem for now and use an orchestration to block duplicate files. I'll keep watching this thread in case someone has an interesting idea.

Comment: Can you check if you have a different **Max Degree of Parallelism** setting? It should be **1**. Please Check [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/899000)